# Tkinter multiple tabs: (Multithreading or Multiprocessing)

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am building a tkinter gui program with multiple tabs and perform object detection in each tab. I just wonder shall I use multiprocessing for each tab like Google Chrome or just use multithreading. Which design would be better in term of performance in this context?

Comment: All tkinter processes must use the same thread, so tkinter does not play a role in your question. Whatever computation goes into whatever is shown in the tab can be threaded or multiprocessed, but which to use is very dependent on what that computation is. As a general rule, use multiprocessing for CPU bound programs, and threading for IO bound programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use whatever you want for *worker threads*, but only a single thread (the "GUI thread") can actually draw things on the screen.

That's how it happens in browsers, too -- slave processes basically render pages in memory and send pixel data to the master process that draws them; the master process sends back user input and such.

Rendering standard GUI elements in memory isn't possible for most stock GUI toolkits, including Tk ('cuz it's an uncommon requirement) so you can't do that. It is typically possible at windowing system level (e.g. [in Windows, it's via `MemoryDC`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224754/Guide-to-Win32-Memory-DC)) which is what browsers take advantage of.